# Algebra with square roots and fractions.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a problem that I simplify to equal 
$\frac{\sqrt{x + h - 9} -\sqrt{x - 9}}{h}$

I thought this would be as far as I could take it but the answer in the book shows 
$\frac{1}{\sqrt{x + h - 9} + \sqrt{x - 9}}$

Can someone please tell me how you get from $\frac{\sqrt{x + h - 9} -\sqrt{x - 9}}{h}$ to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x + h - 9} + \sqrt{x - 9}}$ ?

To add more background. I am tasked with simplifying $\frac{F(x+h) - F(x)}{h}$ where F is a function defined as F(x) = $\sqrt{x - 9}$  so I get it to $\frac{\sqrt{x + h - 9} -\sqrt{x - 9}}{h}$ but the book gives $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x + h - 9} + \sqrt{x - 9}}$  But I don't know how to get the answer in the book.

Comment: I haven't gotten to derivatives yet.  I'm in pre-calc.

Comment: Check your minus signs.

Comment: @Rocket Man.  I fixed the minus.  Thank you!

Comment: Hint: $a-b=\dfrac{a^2-b^2}{a+b}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{\sqrt{x+h-9}-\sqrt{x-9}}{h}=\frac{\sqrt{x+h-9}-\sqrt{x-9}}{h}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{x+h-9}+\sqrt{x-9}}{\sqrt{x+h-9}+\sqrt{x-9}}=
\\
=\frac{\sqrt{x+h-9}^2-\sqrt{x-9}^2}{h\cdot\sqrt{x+h-9}+\sqrt{x-9}} =
\frac{(x+h-9)-(x-9)}{h\cdot\sqrt{x+h-9}+\sqrt{x-9}} =
\\
= \frac{h}{h\cdot\sqrt{x+h-9}+\sqrt{x-9}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x+h-9}+\sqrt{x-9}}
$$

Answer (score 0):

it is $$\frac{\sqrt{x+h-9}-\sqrt{x-9}}{h}=\frac{x+h-9-x+9}{h(\sqrt{x+h-9}+\sqrt{x-9})}$$ 
so we get
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+h-9}+\sqrt{x-9}}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x-9}}$$

Comment: Thank you.  Can you please show me the next steps to get it to the end?  I'm still not sure by your post.